# Installed gems are not being installed correctly. How can I get them to install properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I'm using Mac OS 10.7, RVM 1.8.2, Ruby 1.9.2.

Everything has been working fine, but once I tried to upgrade one of my Rails Apps to 3.1, all of a sudden I started running into problems installing gems. I would run "bundle install" and it would say that the required gems are installed and there are directories for the gems in my .rvm home directory, but when I attempt to start my application it will say that it cannot find the required gems. Running "gem list" does not list the gems that were supposedly installed. I will include an example of this below:

http://pastebin.com/RdK0q1vN

Any idea why the gems are installing, but not being recognized?

Comment: Not sure... can you also run bundle update and see if that helps at all?

Comment: bundle update has the same exact behavior as bundle install. It says it installed the required gems, but then the gems aren't found and used.

Comment: Are you using the appropriate gemset?

Comment: I'm installing them under the same gemset I'm trying to use them from. I've even looked into the gemset's directory to verify that the gems are installed there and they are. I ended up reinstalling RVM and things seem to be working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling RVM and things seem to be working again